# Laravel + Android

Tags: php, android, laravel

Estou começando meus estudos no framework laravel e vi que ele é bem útil para criar websites, porém, é possível eu consumir essas rotas em android nativo ? Porque as rotas normalmente estão ligadas à views e não ao retorno de json por exemplo.

Comment: No caso você criaria rotas na api e faria a integração do seu app via http requests.

Answer (score 1):

rotas é um conceito de desenvolvimento web o android já usa um conceito de orientação a eventos.

Se a pergunta é se da para criar rotas no android a resposta é não, pois a interação do usuário vem por intermédio de um evento que ele dispare